# How to simplify this expression to get the target expression by induction.

Tags: proof-writing, induction

I'm doing the OCR MEI further maths Pure 1 2017 exam paper, checked the mark scheme but i still dont understand the working out of the simplification of the expression.

There is one question that i can understand how they simplified the question below to get the target expression.

$$\sum_{i=1}^ {k+1} \frac{r}{2^r}= 2-(\frac{1}{2})^k (2+k)+\frac{k+1}{2^{k+1}}$$

The target is:

$$\sum_{i=1}^ {k+1}\frac{r}{2^r}=2-(\frac{1}{2})^{k+1}(3+k) $$

Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The simplification of the RHS comes from

\begin{align}
2 - \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^k \left(2+k\right)+\frac{k+1}{2^{k+1}} &= 2-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k+1} 2\left(2+k\right)-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k+1}\left(-k-1\right)\\
&= 2-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k+1}\left(4 + 2k - k - 1\right) \\
&= 2-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k+1}\left(3 + k\right)
\end{align}

In the first line above, I multiplied the numerator & denominator by $2$ in the second terms and took out a factor of $-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k+1}$ in the third term. In the second line, I combined & simplified the second & third terms from the line above.